# Access one object from another?

Tags: java

I know it's absolutely dull question (so newbie) but i'm stuck. How can access fields of one object from another object? 
The question => how to avoid creating Test02 object twice? (1st time => from main() loop, 2nd time => from constructor of Test01)?

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test02 test02 = new Test02();
        Test01 test01 = new Test01(); //NullPointerException => can't access test02.x from test01
        System.out.println(test01.x); 

    }
}

class Test01
{
    int x;
    Test02 test02; //can't access this, why? I creat test02 object in main() loop before test01

    public Test01()
    {
        x = test02.x;
    }
}

class Test02
{
    int x = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have to instantiate test02 in Test01 (eg. in constructor) or pass the instantiated object in main to Test01

so either:

```
public Test01()
    {
        x = new Test02();
//...
    }
```

or

```
class Test01
{
    int x;
    Test02 test02; //the default value for objects is null you have to instantiate with new operator or pass it as a reference variable

    public Test01(Test02 test02)
    {
        this.test02 = test02; // this case test02 shadows the field variable test02 that is why 'this' is used
        x = test02.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: You got it! The 2nd way = exactly what i need! I'm so happy!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create an instance of `Test02`, so you'll get a `NullPointerException` whenever you try to access `test02` from `Test01`'s constructor.

To remedy this, redefine your `Test01` class's constructor like this -

```
class Test01
{
    int x;
    Test02 test02; // need to assign an instance to this reference.

    public Test01()
    {
        test02 = new Test02();    // create instance.
        x = test02.x;
    }
}
```

Or, you can pass an instance of `Test02` from `Main` -

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test02 test02 = new Test02();
        Test01 test01 = new Test01(test02); //NullPointerException => can't access test02.x from test01
        System.out.println(test01.x); 

    }
}

class Test01
{
    int x;
    Test02 test02; //can't access this, why? I creat test02 object in main() loop before test01

    public Test01(Test02 test02)
    {
        this.test02 = test02;
        x = test02.x;
    }
}

class Test02
{
    int x = 10;
}
```

The reason is that whenever you try to create an instance of `Test01`, it tries to access the `test02` variable in its constructor. But the `test02` variable doesn't point to any valid object at this moment. That's why you will get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I know. I just don't wanna create the same object twice? (the solution abote => pass it as reference to ctor()). It's gotta work!

Answer (score 1):

```
Test02 test02 = new Test02();
```

test02 object created have scope for main method only .

`x = test02.x;` it will give null pointer because no object created !